# Azure Managed Lustre or another setup that allows Ubuntu VMs to perform parallel read/write operations to a shared block storage in the cloud?

Tags: azure, pacemaker, ocfs2, gfs2, lustre

I set up Azure Managed Lustre with 8TB and maximum throughput 4GB/s.

Following the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-managed-lustre/connect-clients) for an `Ubuntu 20.04` VM with size `Standard_L8as_v3`, I manage to mount the file system.

Then I test my setup using `dd` and `fio` in the following commands: 
Writing:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=<mount_directory>/testfile bs=1G count=5 oflag=dsync && sync && echo "Write Test Completed"

fio --name=write_test --directory=<mount_directory> --ioengine=libaio --rw=write --bs=1M --direct=1 --size=1G --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

Reading:

```
dd if=<mount_directory>/testfile of=/dev/null bs=1G iflag=dsync && echo "Read Test Completed"

fio --name=read_test --directory=<mount_directory> --ioengine=libaio --rw=read --bs=1M --direct=1 --size=1G --numjobs=1 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

I'm getting speeds that are very low: Around 100MB/s for both reading and writing. Is this really what this product provides? I am sure I am doing something wrong. This cannot be what a file system like `lustre` provides.

I've searched in all in many places (Youtube, Official docs, [Azure High Performance Computing (HPC) Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-high-performance-computing/bg-p/AzureHighPerformanceComputingBlog), Cloud Academy, A Cloug Guru, coursera, edX, Udemy, codementor.io) and I can't find any demonstration of someone using this product, or someone who is willing to get paid for showing me how to configure such setup. I know it's new, but is no one in need of such a solution for ? Is everyone installing their own file system and managing it in house?

By the way, regarding custom solution with file system and a management tool, I also did not find any contemporary demonstrations or walkthrough, which are newer than, say, 7 years ago, involving the implementation of a shared block storage with cluster-aware file system between Ubuntu VMs as nodes on Azure.

As an example, I tried to look for instructions on how to create an Azure setup composed of `OCFS2` or `GFS2` file system (or `ceph`, or `gclusterfs`) for the shared data disk, and Pacemaker as a cluster management system, and I just couldn't find anything. This seems crucial for setups in which people train neural models for example in one VM, and then another production VM is served that data, but still I cannot find anything! I must be missing something. Does anyone have a walkthrough of this process with Azure or another cloud provider?

Final note: Why does Azure call "Shared Disks" shared, if you [must have a cluster management system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared) to actually share the "shared" disks? If all "shared disks" without a cluster management system can do is just get mounted to different VMs, and the VMs can only just read from these disks, not write to it in the same way one considers writing to a disk, then how is "disk" what is shared here?

In any case, I would love someone to enlighten me about Azure Managed Lustre or any contemporary setup that allows Ubuntu VMs to perform parallel read/write operations to a shared block storage in the cloud, including benchmarks for this setup, and I would be happy to [pay](https://www.codementor.io/u/dashboard/my-requests/j1jktgduwq) for such demonstration.